# HI, i need to change materialtextfield dialog choices title and buttons colors in xamarin forms using XFMaterial plugin

Tags: xamarin.forms

im using XFMaterial plugin in xamarin forms. Using materialtextfield with inputtype as choice, i cant change the dialog title and color. I need to change them. Can anyone help me.

Comment: I think they provide you to set the configuration. 
Please post your existing code that you have so that we can help/suggest. Without that we have no idea what you are upto.

Comment: This is my code, i set the choices in the code behind.<material:MaterialTextField InputType="Choice" x:Name="montoPicker" AlwaysShowUnderline="True" TintColor="#9E9E9E" BackgroundColor="Transparent" TextFontFamily="{StaticResource RobotoRegularFont}" ChoiceSelected="MontoPicker_ChoiceSelected" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>